# Detection and segmentation of region of interest from X-ray images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on some Xray images and I want to detect and segment region of interest from the image.

Consider input image

[image]

I want to detect square like shapes in the image, as highlighted in the image

[image]

Output: region of interest will somehow look like this

[image]

This is my code which I have done so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from skimage.io import imread, imshow


img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
imshow(img)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imshow(gray)

equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
imshow(equ)


img_resize = cv2.resize(img, (300, 300))
print(img_resize.shape)
figure_size = 9

new_image_gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_resize, (figure_size, figure_size),0)
imshow(new_image_gauss)


img_edge = cv2.Canny(equ,100,200)

# show the image edges on the newly created image window
imshow(img_edge)


kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) 
img_erosion = cv2.erode(img_edge, kernel, iterations=1) 
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(img_edge, kernel, iterations=1) 
   
imshow(img_erosion)
```

Results which I have got;

[image]
[image]

Please guide me.

TIA

Comment: On Stack Overflow you're expected to produce the code you've written in order to assess its behaviour ("Why doesn't this code correctly identify square shapes?"). As it stands, I'm afraid the question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I shared my work which I have done so far

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help is to do morphology gradient on your image to emphasize the edges in Python OpenCV before you do your Canny edge detection.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("xray2.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# do morphology gradient
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

# apply gain
morph = cv2.multiply(morph, 5)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("xray2_gradient_edges.jpg",morph)

# show lines
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing tips. 
I applied morphology gradient as you mentioned and after that I used edge detector but not get good results